# GStreamer multiple appsrc cause the application to crash

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have a problem with GStreamer 1.0 when multiple appsrc are used in the same pipeline.
The pipeline receives data from two different sources, and mix them into a single video using videomixer element. Pipeline is as following:

```
 videomixer name=mix \
 appsrc name=src0 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=640,height=480,framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert  ! video/x-raw,format=I420  ! videobox left=-0  ! mix.sink_0 \
 appsrc name=src1 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=640,height=480,framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert  ! video/x-raw,format=I420  ! videobox left=-640  ! mix.sink_1 \
 mix.  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Each appsrc registers callback functions using: GstAppSrcCallbacks

When I run the application, it immediately crashes after each appsrc receives two or three frames (it crashes randomly). No error being reported on the console, or in the pipeline bus message listener. I don't get any error messages at all.

If I tried to run with a single appsrc without the mixer, it runs without any problem:

```
appsrc name=src0 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=640,height=480,framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert  ! video/x-raw,format=I420  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

GStreamer Version:1.5.2 / Windows

**Edit**
Here is the code I am using to init the appsrc:

```
GstAppSrcCallbacks srcCB;
GstAppSrc* videoSrc;
videoSrc = GST_APP_SRC(gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(GetPipeline()), "src0"));
srcCB.need_data = &start_feed;
srcCB.enough_data = &stop_feed;
srcCB.seek_data = &seek_data;
gst_app_src_set_callbacks(videoSrc, &srcCB, this, NULL);


static void start_feed(GstAppSrc *source, guint size, gpointer data)
{
    VideoSrcData* o = static_cast<VideoSrcData*>(data);
    if (o->sourceID == 0) {
        GST_DEBUG("start feeding");
        o->sourceID = g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)read_data, o);
    }
}

static gboolean read_data(VideoSrcData *d)
{
    GstFlowReturn ret;

    GstBuffer *buffer;
    if (NeedBuffer(0, &buffer) == GST_FLOW_OK)
    {
        ret = gst_app_src_push_buffer(d->videoSrc, buffer);
        if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK){
            ret = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(d->videoSrc);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;

}

GstFlowReturn NeedBuffer(GstMySrc * sink, GstBuffer ** buffer)
{
    if (!m_grabber->GrabFrame()) //ask video grabber to prepare image frame
    {
        return GST_FLOW_ERROR;
    }
    m_grabber->Lock();

    //Get Image frame
    const video::ImageInfo* ifo = m_grabber->GetLastFrame();
    int len = ifo->imageDataSize;
    GstMapInfo map;
    GstBuffer* outbuf = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(len);
    gst_buffer_map(outbuf, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
    memcpy(map.data, ifo->imageData, len);
    gst_buffer_unmap(outbuf, &map);
    m_grabber->Unlock();
    *buffer = outbuf;
    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}
```

I confirmed that data size and format is matching the requested one in the pipeline caps

**Update 1:**

After several trials, it seems even when one appsrc is used in a videomixer, the application would crash. Example pipeline:

```
 videomixer name=mix \
 appsrc name=src0 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=640,height=480,framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert  ! video/x-raw,format=I420  ! videobox left=-0  ! mix.sink_0 \
 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=640,height=480,framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert  ! video/x-raw,format=I420  ! videobox left=-640  ! mix.sink_1 \
 mix.  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Comment: You probably have a segfault of some kind going on.  Can you run the program in a debugger and get a line number?  At the minimum you need to paste the pertinent source used by your appsrc elements.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I am using to push data to the pipeline. About debugging the application, I have tried to debug it several time, but the application just exits with no exception or any message reported, and it doesn't break at any line code or even assembly code... I think after several trials its related with the videomixer, because even if I used a single appsrc, the application would crash

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that's odd is here:

```
GstAppSrcCallbacks srcCB;
GstAppSrc* videoSrc;
videoSrc = GST_APP_SRC(gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(GetPipeline()), "src0"));
srcCB.need_data = &start_feed;
srcCB.enough_data = &stop_feed;
srcCB.seek_data = &seek_data;
```

Where you point to the address of some function, and really you should just be able to assign it.

```
srcCB.need_data = start_feed;
srcCB.enough_data = stop_feed;
srcCB.seek_data = seek_data;
```

Also, can you try not using your m_grabber object and see if it works?  Make each appsrc just fill their buffer with a different color.

What are you using to debug?  If your app crashes the debugger should halt and allow you to examine the active threads and find the offending line number.